# Using two self joins to find the subordinates of managers' subordinates

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

So let's say I have a table that includes employees and their direct supervisor (as denoted by `parentEmployeeKey`). How do I return the number of subordinates of a given employee, as well as how many subordinates are underneath their subordinates (indirect subordinates). This is kind of what I would imagine the code looking like, but I know there are issues.

```
SELECT
    Employee.EmployeeKey, 
    COUNT(Employee_1.EmployeeKey, 
    COUNT(Employee_2.EmployeeKey) 
FROM 
    Employee
INNER JOIN 
    Employee AS Employee_1 ON Employee_1.ParentEmployeeKey = Employee.EmployeeKey 
INNER JOIN 
    Employee AS Employee_2 ON Employee_2.ParentEmployeeKey = Employee1.EmployeeKey
WHERE
    Employee.blahblah is blahblah
GROUP BY 
    blah blah blah
```

Thank you!

Comment: See [example B here](https://www.sqlservertutorial.net/sql-server-basics/sql-server-recursive-cte/).

Comment: Do you always have exactly 3 levels, or do we need to go down recursively

Comment: Always 3 exactly

Comment: I highly recommend table aliases.

Comment: Sample data + expected results will make it much easier to assist you. Bonus points if you add your sample data as DDL+DML.

Answer (score 0):

Well, here's an example using the form you chose (joins).  Just a couple of adjustments needed.

1. `COUNT` should be `DISTINCT` to protect against `JOIN` behavior. The second count doesn't really need it in this case.
2. `JOIN`s are now `LEFT` outer joins, so we don't lose results that have no subordinates and maybe a little more importantly, those with no sub-subordinates.

If you really wanted only those with at least 1 subordinate, the first `JOIN` could have been an `INNER JOIN`.

Just add the two counts to obtain the total subordinates and sub-subordinates.

```
-- Proposed SQL, in the requested form (joins)
SELECT Employee.EmployeeKey
     , COUNT(DISTINCT Employee_1.EmployeeKey) AS subordinates
     , COUNT(DISTINCT Employee_2.EmployeeKey) AS subsubordinates
  FROM      Employee
  LEFT JOIN Employee AS Employee_1 ON Employee_1.ParentEmployeeKey = Employee.EmployeeKey
  LEFT JOIN Employee AS Employee_2 ON Employee_2.ParentEmployeeKey = Employee_1.EmployeeKey
 GROUP BY Employee.EmployeeKey
;
```

The test case:

[Test case for sql-server](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=8d55e72284fc4a592ecfc8ec155c267b)